# In hadoop programming, where is partition, comparison?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In hadoop programs , i have always seen mapper and reducer class.
But mapreduce algorithm is a combination of

- map
- comparison
- partition
- reduce

So where are partition, comparison processes in program?

Comment: How is it related to cloudera?

Comment: Not specific with cloudera.Just about hadoop.These processes are part of mapreduce framework as per [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) article but i am not creating any function to do so.

Comment: ok, but I think my question is fairly valid. This has happened 2 times. For valid question I am getting down votes. It is not like I am putting random queries, I DO have some research behind all this. I turn up here, for some guidance, and I see down votes, next day I am blocked to ask questions! Weird community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [these posts](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/tag/tutorial/). They present map/reduce, partitioner, combiner and counters

Comment: it is probably because it is hard to understand what you mean by "So where are partition, comparison processes in program?"

Answer (score 0):

A good place where you can figure things out is if you go into your hadoop deployment, and checkout the source code. Most of the time you can find your answers there. Give it a go! :)